# Why are the other properties of the object in a Spring @MVC form becoming null?

Tags: forms, data-binding, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a form using Spring @MVC 3.0.  This form is supposed to let the user update the flavor of a soup, but I'm running into some issues.  Here are my relevant model classes (assume all the getters and setters are there):

```
public class Soup {
   String name, flavor, mainIngredient;
   public String toString() 
   {
      return "name: " + this.name + ", flavor: " 
             + this.flavor + ", main: " + this.mainIngredient;
   }
}

public class SmallMeal {
    List<Soup> soups;
}

public class Menu {
    String id;
    SmallMeal smallMeals;
}
```

This part of the application allows the user to edit the soups.  Here's the controller:

```
public class MenuController {

  @RequestMapping(value="/soupForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String updateSoups(
     @PathVariable("menuId") String menuId,
     ModelMap model) 
  {
     Menu menu = // ... looked up with a DAO.
     if (menu != null)
     {
        model.addAttribute("menu", menu);
        for (Soup s : menu.getSmallMeal().getSoups())
        {
           System.out.println("soup: " + s.toString());
        }
     }
     return "soupEditor";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/soupForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String updateSoups(
     @ModelAttribute("menu") Menu menu,
     BindingResult result, SessionStatus status)
  {
     for (Soup s : menu.getSmallMeal().getSoups())
     {
        System.out.println("soup: " + s.toString());
     }
     return "redirect:soupUpdated";
  }

}
```

And here's the `soupForm` JSP:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="menu">
  <c:forEach var="soup" varStatus="stat" items="${menu.smallMeal.soups}">
     <label>${soup.name} flavor</label>
     <form:input path="smallMeal.soups[${stat.index}].flavor" />
  </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

Now, when I first request the page, I get an output similar to this:

```
name: tortilla, flavor: spicy, mainIngredient: tortillas
name: crab bisque, flavor: crab, mainIngredient: crab
```

And after I submit the form (after updating the flavor for `tortilla`), I would get an output similar to:

```
name: null, flavor: delicious, mainIngredient: null
name: null, flavor: null, mainIngredient: null
```

What's going wrong?  Why isn't the rest of the data of the object being bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the `@SessionAttributes` annotation was the answer.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("menu")
public class MenuController { 

  /* ... */

}
```

After that was added, the data currently existing on the object persisted.